# Can't access file in the /mnt/shared on Gennymotion

Tags: macos, genymotion

I had configured shared folder for my virtual device on virtualbox. (Auto mount, Make permanent)
So i access /mnt/shared/[mysharedfolder]/ but it is was empty.

I'm using Mavericks OS. I can see my shared folders but nothing inside them.

Comment: Same problem here: VirtualBox + AndroVM in Fedora 20.

Comment: It was a permission problem in my case. Be sure that locally you have read and execute permissions for all in your `mysharedfolder`. However, I have an empty `/mnt/shared` in Genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

Use a fully permission folder (including files) as your vbox shared folder. I use my Public folder in Home directory in Linux.